# Why does Django tell me that a field clashes with a field in the base class when that field only exists in the subclass?

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to define some models that inherit from a base class with timestamps, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/mtm/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/mtm/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/mtm/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 436, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
events.Event.location: (models.E006) The field 'location' clashes with the field 'location' from model 'home.timestampedmodel'.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

Here are my models:

### home/models.py

```py
from django.db import models

class TimestampedModel(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

### events/models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from home.models import TimestampedModel

class Location(TimestampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='Chicago')
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='IL')

class Event(TimestampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField()
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The code runs successfully when I have `Location` and `Event` inherit from `models.Model`, but this isn't how I want my code to be structured.

### events/models.py (works, but not desirable)

```py
from django.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='Chicago')
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='IL')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField()
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Why am I running into this error? Is there any way to include `date_created` and `date_updated` in my models without defining them explicitly every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make timestampedmodel abstract

```
class TimestampedModel(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```